# Converting zoom level rule-based styles to mbtiles?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, convert, style, mbtiles

In QGIS I have made a zoom level rule-based style (`.qml`) with OpenStreetMap data stored locally for a specific area.

Is it possible that I convert these styles (or the project) as `mbtiles` so that I can host it as a basemap for my Leaflet project?

Comment: Which format defines your "zoom level rule-based style", is it XML or CartoCSS? Do you store your data in PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension? Have you seen these software [TileMill | Exporting a map](http://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/exporting/) or [Export your Kosmtik project in MBTiles](https://github.com/kosmtik/kosmtik-mbtiles-export)?

Comment: Hi Taras, these are just QGIS style files with .qml extension. The data is stored locally as layers in QGIS. I was looking for something like QTiles (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qtiles/) to do the job. 

I can store the data in my PostgreSQL database with PostGIS extension enabled. If I do this then what would be an ideal way to proceed? I heard of TileMill before but wasn't sure if it's still maintained, I'll have a look at it today.

Comment: Have you seen this topic [QGIS Project to MBTILES / SLIPPY MAPS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268030/qgis-project-to-mbtiles-slippy-maps) as well?

Comment: Thanks Taras, it looks promising. I'll study this a bit more.